# Xperia U (kumquat) cm10 camera problems

Tags: android, sony, sony-xperia

As you may know, FXP team is trying to build *CyanogenMod 10* for all *NovaThor* Devices. However, they are facing problem with camera, expecially with *Sony Xperia U* (kumquat), *Go* and *Sola*. So, I in looked deep in camera logcat and I found that in every log there are those errors:

```
E/OSTTRACE( 1512): ! ERROR :imaging/hsmcamera/src/camera.cpp:2588:OMX handle 0x41bf4138: ID 3:Error: mpImgNetwork->construct() 0xFFFFFFC4
```

and:

```
E/caladbolg( 1512):  245827698 cald_hal_omx_util.cpp             (1075)  1878 E [HAL] OMX.ST.HSMCamera: EventError: 80001009,0
```

Does someone know how to correct this error? (p.s.: I'm not a skilled dev, I'm just trying to help the dev community to get cm10 working on our devices! )

Answer (score 0):

as we stated before we will investigate camera after audio will be fixed 
there is no need to rush and fix camera since without stable audio this device can not be used for its normal purpose (PHONE)